# C - Read in float value using getchar and print out float using printf

Tags: c

I'm extremely lost and confused.

I have to read in a float integer like 3.432 using getchar. Then, I have to print it out again as a float with a precision of 4 decimal places using printf. So 3.432 --> 3.4320 and .450 --> .4500, and 453 --> 453.0000.

I've been using getchar() and I understand that, but trying to reconvert the value as a float is where I'm just extremely lost.

```
 float num = 0.0;
 char ch;
 while((ch = getchar()) != '\n'){
      num = ch - '0';
      printf("%.4f", num);
 }
```

I know why that is wrong and what it outputs but that's what I have so far

EDIT: I can only use getchar to read the float values

Comment: what value is going to happen in `num` when `ch` contains the decimal point. i.e  at `num = ch - '0';` ?

Comment: yes I can only use getchar, no atof. I was looking at casting it to a float but then each individual character is a float

Comment: Your code snippet is a good start, but where exactly is your problem ?

Answer (score 6):

Not tested (no time). Hope it helps.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float num = 0.0;
    float i = 1.0;
    char ch;

    printf("Enter a float number: ");

    while((ch = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        if (ch == '.')
        {
            i = 0.1;
        }
        else if ((ch>= '0') && (ch <='9'))
        {
            if (i==1)
            {
                num *= 10;
                num += ch - '0';
            }
            else
            {
                num += (ch - '0') * i;
                i /= 10;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%.4f\n", num);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so you should first specify what you want - as usual keep away from the keybord until you exactly know what you want to build:

- read until end of file or first new line
- skip initial blank characters (optional but not expensive)
- ignore trailing blank character (optional but not expensive)
- reject any non blank after first trailing blank
- reject any character other than blanks, digits and dot
- process the integer part (until first dot) but multiplying current value by 10 and adding character code minus char '0'
- ensure at most one dot
- process the decimal part by adding char - '0' multiplied by 0.1 power decimal position

Once that has been stated coding is simple and could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void error(int pos, char c) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unwanted character %c at %d\n", c, pos);
    exit(1);
}

int main() {
    double f = 0.;
    int c;
    bool initial = 1, final=0;
    int pos = 0;
    double decimal = 0;

    while (((c = getchar()) != EOF) && (c != '\n')) {
        pos += 1;
        if (isspace(c)) { // accept spaces before and after the number
            if (initial || final) continue;
            else {
                final = 1;
                continue;
            }
        }
        else if (final) {  // do not accept anything after a space after the number
            error(pos, c);
        }
        initial = 0;     // at least one non blank char
        if (c == '.') {
            if (decimal) { // accept only one decimal dot
                error(pos, c);
            }
            else decimal = 1;
        }
        else if (! isdigit(c)) { // only digits
            error(pos, c);
        }
        else if (decimal == 0) {
            f = f * 10 + c - '0';   // integer part
        }
        else {
            decimal *= .1;     // fractional part
            f += (c - '0') * decimal;
        }
    }
    printf("%.4f\n", f);

    return 0;
}
```

As a bonus I showed you how to process error conditions

Answer (score 0):

It would be simpler if you first write a function reading integer.

Then you can think about writing a function reading the decimal part and combine the result.

Also, you need to accumulate the read information. At the moment you are overwriting previously read digit with a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility using only `stdio` in solving the task could be a simple two-step process:

- declaring and reading the input into a character array, using some more or less sophisticated fool-proofing
- "parsing" the array members on the left and right hand side of the decimal point and multiplying the ('0' offset subtracted value) by the corresponding power of 10.

_

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  float power_of_ten, num = 0.;
  char c, ch[32];
  int j, i = 0;
  int point_pos = -1; //initialize decimal point position 'offscale'

  while(((c = getchar()) != EOF) && (c != '\n')) //simple fool-proof check
    if(((c >= '0')&&(c <= '9')) || (( c == '.')&&(point_pos == -1))){
      ch[i] = c;
      if(ch[i] == '.') 
          point_pos = i;
      i++;
      }
  ch[++i] = '\0'; //length of the array
  //parsing the array
  if(point_pos >= 0){  //to the right of decimal point
      power_of_ten = .1;
      for(j = point_pos + 1; j < i-1; j++){      
          num += (float)(ch[j] - '0')*power_of_ten;
          power_of_ten *= .1;
          }
      }

  power_of_ten = 1.;   //to the left of decimal point
  if(point_pos == -1)point_pos = i-1;  
  for(j = point_pos - 1; j >= 0 ; j --){  
      num += (float)(ch[j] - '0')*power_of_ten;
      power_of_ten *= 10;
      }

   printf("%.4f\n", num); 

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Hope this helps!!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
int findNumOfDigits(int num);

int main(void)
{
    char c;
    float f, mod, fractional;
    char *buff = malloc(10), *fptr;
    char *str = buff;
    int digits;
    printf("Enter any number\n");

    c = getchar();
    while(c!='\n')
    {
        *buff = c;
        buff = buff+1;
        c = getchar();
    }
    *buff = '\0';

    mod = atoi(str);
    fptr = strstr(str, ".");
    if(fptr!=NULL)
        fptr++;
    fractional = atoi(fptr);
    digits = findNumOfDigits(fractional);
    f = (mod + (fractional/pow(10,digits)));
    printf("Number converted to float = %f", f);

    return 0;
}

int findNumOfDigits(int num)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 1; num >= 10; i++)
    {
        num = num/10;
    }
    return i;
}
```